# C - Matrices as pass by value?

Tags: c, optimization, matrix, pass-by-value, return-by-value

I'm designing matrix handling functions for a C project. I am considering either passing matrices by value or by reference. I created a benchmark passing matrices by value and by reference, and both appear to perform the same with optimization flag -O0 and -O2 in gcc. Given that my benchmark may be giving incorrect results, I would like to know what is the most efficient way to pass matrices in and out of function calls using only C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// Compiled on OSX 10.6.8 using: cc -o matrix matrix.c -std=c99 -O2

typedef struct {
    float m0;
    float m1;
    float m2;
    float m3;
    float m4;
    float m5;
    float m6;
    float m7;
    float m8;
    float m9;
    float m10;
    float m11;
    float m12;
    float m13;
    float m14;
    float m15;
} Matrix;

// ================================================
//                 Pass By Value
// ------------------------------------------------

Matrix PassByValue (Matrix a, Matrix b) {
    Matrix matrix;

    matrix.m0  = a.m0 * b.m0  + a.m4 * b.m1  + a.m8  * b.m2  + a.m12 * b.m3;
    matrix.m1  = a.m1 * b.m0  + a.m5 * b.m1  + a.m9  * b.m2  + a.m13 * b.m3;
    matrix.m2  = a.m2 * b.m0  + a.m6 * b.m1  + a.m10 * b.m2  + a.m14 * b.m3;
    matrix.m3  = a.m3 * b.m0  + a.m7 * b.m1  + a.m11 * b.m2  + a.m15 * b.m3;

    matrix.m4  = a.m0 * b.m4  + a.m4 * b.m5  + a.m8  * b.m6  + a.m12 * b.m7;
    matrix.m5  = a.m1 * b.m4  + a.m5 * b.m5  + a.m9  * b.m6  + a.m13 * b.m7;
    matrix.m6  = a.m2 * b.m4  + a.m6 * b.m5  + a.m10 * b.m6  + a.m14 * b.m7;
    matrix.m7  = a.m3 * b.m4  + a.m7 * b.m5  + a.m11 * b.m6  + a.m15 * b.m7;

    matrix.m8  = a.m0 * b.m8  + a.m4 * b.m9  + a.m8  * b.m10 + a.m12 * b.m11;
    matrix.m9  = a.m1 * b.m8  + a.m5 * b.m9  + a.m9  * b.m10 + a.m13 * b.m11;
    matrix.m10 = a.m2 * b.m8  + a.m6 * b.m9  + a.m10 * b.m10 + a.m14 * b.m11;
    matrix.m11 = a.m3 * b.m8  + a.m7 * b.m9  + a.m11 * b.m10 + a.m15 * b.m11;

    matrix.m12 = a.m0 * b.m12 + a.m4 * b.m13 + a.m8  * b.m14 + a.m12 * b.m15;
    matrix.m13 = a.m1 * b.m12 + a.m5 * b.m13 + a.m9  * b.m14 + a.m13 * b.m15;
    matrix.m14 = a.m2 * b.m12 + a.m6 * b.m13 + a.m10 * b.m14 + a.m14 * b.m15;
    matrix.m15 = a.m3 * b.m12 + a.m7 * b.m13 + a.m11 * b.m14 + a.m15 * b.m15;

    return matrix;
}


// ================================================
//               Pass By Reference
// ------------------------------------------------

void PassByReference (Matrix* matrix, Matrix* a, Matrix* b) {
    if (!matrix) return;
    if (!a) return;
    if (!b) return;

    matrix->m0  = a->m0 * b->m0  + a->m4 * b->m1  + a->m8  * b->m2  + a->m12 * b->m3;
    matrix->m1  = a->m1 * b->m0  + a->m5 * b->m1  + a->m9  * b->m2  + a->m13 * b->m3;
    matrix->m2  = a->m2 * b->m0  + a->m6 * b->m1  + a->m10 * b->m2  + a->m14 * b->m3;
    matrix->m3  = a->m3 * b->m0  + a->m7 * b->m1  + a->m11 * b->m2  + a->m15 * b->m3;

    matrix->m4  = a->m0 * b->m4  + a->m4 * b->m5  + a->m8  * b->m6  + a->m12 * b->m7;
    matrix->m5  = a->m1 * b->m4  + a->m5 * b->m5  + a->m9  * b->m6  + a->m13 * b->m7;
    matrix->m6  = a->m2 * b->m4  + a->m6 * b->m5  + a->m10 * b->m6  + a->m14 * b->m7;
    matrix->m7  = a->m3 * b->m4  + a->m7 * b->m5  + a->m11 * b->m6  + a->m15 * b->m7;

    matrix->m8  = a->m0 * b->m8  + a->m4 * b->m9  + a->m8  * b->m10 + a->m12 * b->m11;
    matrix->m9  = a->m1 * b->m8  + a->m5 * b->m9  + a->m9  * b->m10 + a->m13 * b->m11;
    matrix->m10 = a->m2 * b->m8  + a->m6 * b->m9  + a->m10 * b->m10 + a->m14 * b->m11;
    matrix->m11 = a->m3 * b->m8  + a->m7 * b->m9  + a->m11 * b->m10 + a->m15 * b->m11;

    matrix->m12 = a->m0 * b->m12 + a->m4 * b->m13 + a->m8  * b->m14 + a->m12 * b->m15;
    matrix->m13 = a->m1 * b->m12 + a->m5 * b->m13 + a->m9  * b->m14 + a->m13 * b->m15;
    matrix->m14 = a->m2 * b->m12 + a->m6 * b->m13 + a->m10 * b->m14 + a->m14 * b->m15;
    matrix->m15 = a->m3 * b->m12 + a->m7 * b->m13 + a->m11 * b->m14 + a->m15 * b->m15;
}

// ================================================
//                  Benchmark
// ------------------------------------------------

#define LOOPS 100000

int main () {
    Matrix result;
    Matrix a;
    Matrix b;
    clock_t begin;
    clock_t end;
    int index;

    // ------------------------------------------
    //          Pass By Reference
    // ------------------------------------------
    begin = clock();
    for (index = 0; index < LOOPS; index++) {

        PassByReference(&result,&a,&b);
        a.m0 += index;
        b.m0 += index;

    }
    end = clock();
    printf("Pass By Ref: %f\n",(double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // ------------------------------------------
    //            Pass By Value
    // ------------------------------------------
    begin = clock();
    for (index = 0; index < LOOPS; index++) {

        result = PassByValue(a,b);
        a.m0 += index;
        b.m0 += index;

    }
    end = clock();
    printf("Pass By Val: %f\n",(double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);


    // The following line along with the above
    // additions in the loops hopefully prevent
    // the matrices from being optimized into
    // nothing.
    printf("%0.1f\n",result.m0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Results:**

```
Pass By Ref: 0.489226
Pass By Val: 0.488882
```

Comment: Why not use a length-16 array, rather than a bunch of individual member variables?

Comment: Individual values in the struct are a common pattern for matrices from what I've seen.

Comment: I'm just impressed you stuck with Snow Leopard =P

Comment: I wrapped the values in a struct to pass by value, and at the time I felt that individual values were cleaner.

Comment: Passing by pointer or reference will have the same performance, and tecnically is the optimal way of doing that. Nobody passes entire structures as parameter to a function, its a very dumb thing to do, you will see there is no function doing that anywhere. If you want to preserve the structure data from being changed, use `const Matrix*` instead.

Comment: @Havenard You should post that as the answer, because it's correct.

Comment: You could still do the same with a `struct Matrix { double m[16]; }` if you wanted to. its not uncommon when people want to pass around arrays by-value to do so (though I strongly advise you go with Havenard's proposal and use `const Matrix *`).

Comment: Consider 3D vectors in programming. You never see struct vector { float val[3] };. You always see struct vector { float x, float y, flaot z };. A matrix is a defined standardized type, just as a vector3 is. Using array syntax almost implies that the size isn't constant.

Comment: @Havenard: The OP is comparing by-value and by-pointer (not by-reference, because this is a C question...)

Comment: Matrix Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix_members.aspx

Comment: @Inisheer: Sure, in the 3D case, the variables have well-recognised distinct names (although I'd argue that you don't always see `x,y,z` instead of an array, it depends on what the aim is.)  But with 16 variables, it's just a mess.  An array has no disadvantages, but has the advantage that you can iterate if you want to.

Comment: Havenard is spot on, but also your test is timing the calculations as well, which probably swamp the overhead of the call mechanism, especially as the matrix is quite small and all the data probably remained in L1/L2 cache. Just an observation.

Comment: cocoa passes NSRect NSPOint NSSize by value all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 competing interests here:

1. passing a struct by value, this gets typed as data storage class and pushed onto the stack by the x86 calling convention, this is a little bit slower than a by ref call that will get stuck in a register.
2. this is almost exactly balanced by a bunch of pointer dereferences...

seperate and profile each part separately

if you are trying to make this kind of code faster you may be able to write faster implementations in some sort of SIMD code, AltiVec, SSE or OpenCL depending

Comment: I took your advice in #2 and tested the pass by pointer function using an array of 16 floats. Now passing by reference (which I probably should have called pass by pointer from the comments) shows up as being 3-4 times faster.

Comment: @user2221841 in c++ there is such a thing as by reference... which is passing by pointer with the compiler doing the magical dereferencing for you, but in std C I think people generally know what you mean, even if it isn't semantically 100% correct.

Comment: Using icc 13.1 calling by reference beats calling by value by approx. 14% if you use each and every value of the matrix (tested for sizes up to 2048), if you only use one value, calling by reference is magnitudes better (~5000%)

Comment: @hroptatyr yeah you expect the problem to get worse the bigger they get as passing by ref is basically bigO 1 and by value is big O n best case... for the actual function predicate construction ...

Answer (score 0):

From Effective C++:

> Prefer pass-by-reference-to-const over pass-by-value, it's typically
>   more efficient and it avoids the slicing problem. The rule doesn't
>   apply to built-in types and STL iterator and function object types.
>   For them, pass-by-value is usually appropriate.

I understand that you are programming in C instead of C++, but I think this rule still applies. The reason why your example of these two performs very close could be that the struct contains only float and is inexpensive to copy as it is passed by value.

However, like the author of Effective C++ said

> some compilers refuse to put objects consisting of only a double into
>   a register, even though they happily place naked doubles there on a
>   regular basis. When that kind of thing happens, you can be better of
>   passing such objects by reference, because compliers will certainly
>   put pointers into registers".Unsubscribe-lgm-thur

In your case, maybe machine doesn't mind to put the struct in the register, but it's hard to tell when you run your program on other machines. Since their performance are really close, I would vote for passing by reference.

Answer (score 0):

32 float values won't fit into the registers anyway. The compiler will be forced to push the data from memory onto the stack, which is just another part of the memory. Depending on the number of data accesses it may be even slower to copy the data instead of dereferencing pointers.

I would suggest using pass-by-reference with const modifier for any non-scalar data. It's the job of the compiler to optimize your code for specific platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, we only have 'pass-by-value' in C. You should pass matrix pointers (by value) to the function. It will reduce the data 'copied' into the function and hence more efficient.